# conversion failed when converting the varchar value to datatype int excel VBA error

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have written the below VBA to extract a field based on a cell reference in excel. The cell contains a date. cannot figure why the error.
The sql field is setup as varchar, the excel cell is formatted as mm/dd/yyyy.

```
string1 = "SELECT Events FROM Calendar WHERE calendarDate =" & d1
rs.Open string1, cn
```

d1 contains the date in excel and is defined as a "Date" in my code.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: try `string1 = "SELECT Events FROM Calendar WHERE calendarDate = '" & d1.text & "'"`

Comment: It could also be that Excel stores dates as a Long integer (regardless of how you have it formatted.)

Comment: A quick question is `d1` the address or a range variable?  If it is the address then: `string1 = "SELECT Events FROM Calendar WHERE calendarDate = '" & Range("d1").text & "'"`

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you Scott, I will try it and revert. you are correct d1 is a cell reference that contains the date to retrieve from the database.

Comment: @ScottCraner you code worked mate. thank you so much! I'd like to give you the credit by marking your answer as correct, but I think you added a comment instead of an answer.. will wait if you'd like to change it :)